# Files Include/Exclude based on subfolder name

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I have the following file structure:

```
\RootFolder\
\RootFolder\SubFolder1\
\RootFolder\SubFolder1\SubfolderA\
\RootFolder\SubFolder1\SubfolderA\bin\
\RootFolder\SubFolder1\SubfolderA\bin\MySameNameFile1.txt
\RootFolder\SubFolder1\SubfolderA\bin\MySameNameFile2.txt
\RootFolder\SubFolder1\SubfolderA\bin\MySameNameFile3.txt
\RootFolder\SubFolder1\SubfolderA\bin\DontWantFile.txt
\RootFolder\SubFolder1\SubfolderA\obj\
\RootFolder\SubFolder1\SubfolderA\obj\MySameNameFile1.txt
\RootFolder\SubFolder1\SubfolderA\obj\MySameNameFile2.txt
\RootFolder\SubFolder1\SubfolderA\obj\MySameNameFile3.txt


\RootFolder\SubFolder2\
\RootFolder\SubFolder2\SubfolderB\
\RootFolder\SubFolder2\SubfolderB\bin\
\RootFolder\SubFolder2\SubfolderB\bin\MySameNameFile1.txt
\RootFolder\SubFolder2\SubfolderB\bin\MySameNameFile2.txt
\RootFolder\SubFolder2\SubfolderB\bin\MySameNameFile3.txt
\RootFolder\SubFolder2\SubfolderB\bin\DontWantFile.txt

\RootFolder\SubFolder2\SubFolder2\obj\
\RootFolder\SubFolder2\SubfolderB\obj\MySameNameFile1.txt
\RootFolder\SubFolder2\SubfolderB\obj\MySameNameFile2.txt
\RootFolder\SubFolder2\SubfolderB\obj\MySameNameFile3.txt


\RootFolder\SubFolder3\
\RootFolder\SubFolder3\SubfolderC\
\RootFolder\SubFolder3\SubfolderC\bin\
\RootFolder\SubFolder3\SubfolderC\bin\MySameNameFile1.txt
\RootFolder\SubFolder3\SubfolderC\bin\MySameNameFile2.txt
\RootFolder\SubFolder3\SubfolderC\bin\MySameNameFile3.txt
\RootFolder\SubFolder3\SubfolderC\bin\DontWantFile.txt

\RootFolder\SubFolder3\SubfolderC\obj\
\RootFolder\SubFolder3\SubfolderC\obj\MySameNameFile1.txt
\RootFolder\SubFolder3\SubfolderC\obj\MySameNameFile2.txt
\RootFolder\SubFolder3\SubfolderC\obj\MySameNameFile3.txt
```

I'm trying to get all "MySameNameFile*.*" files, but NOT the ones in the \obj\ directories.

What I've tried:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MyRootFolderVariable>.\RootFolder\</MyRootFolderVariable>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="MyTarget">

    <ItemGroup>
        <MyExcludeFiles Include="$(MyRootFolderVariable)\**\obj\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <MyIncludeFiles Include="$(MyRootFolderVariable)\**\*MySameNameFile*.txt" Exclude="@(MyExcludeFiles)" />
    </ItemGroup>  

    <PropertyGroup>
        <BinFilesButNoObjFiles>@(MyIncludeFiles->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;' , ' ')</BinFilesButNoObjFiles>
    </PropertyGroup>  

    <Message Text="BinFilesButNoObjFiles=$(BinFilesButNoObjFiles)"/>
    <Message Text="   "/>
    <Message Text="   "/>

</Target>
```

Files I'm after:

```
\RootFolder\SubFolder1\SubfolderA\bin\MySameNameFile1.txt
\RootFolder\SubFolder1\SubfolderA\bin\MySameNameFile2.txt
\RootFolder\SubFolder1\SubfolderA\bin\MySameNameFile3.txt

\RootFolder\SubFolder2\SubfolderB\bin\MySameNameFile1.txt
\RootFolder\SubFolder2\SubfolderB\bin\MySameNameFile2.txt
\RootFolder\SubFolder2\SubfolderB\bin\MySameNameFile3.txt

\RootFolder\SubFolder3\SubfolderC\bin\MySameNameFile1.txt
\RootFolder\SubFolder3\SubfolderC\bin\MySameNameFile2.txt
\RootFolder\SubFolder3\SubfolderC\bin\MySameNameFile3.txt
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Code seems perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was close.  Note the second "**" in the answer below.

```
 <MyExcludeFiles Include="$(MyRootFolderVariable)\**\obj\**\*.*" />
```